# Why it can be asserted that the bottom plate takes the highest potential and the top plates takes the lowest of the capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, capacitance, flux, dielectric

[image]

The ideal parallel capacitor has been filled with 2  dielectrics as shown in the above diagram.

$$  V_{1} :=\text{potential at the top plate}  $$

$$  V_{2} :=\text{potential at the bottom plate}  $$

$$ V'  :=\text{ potential at the border between the dielectrics }  $$

$$ V  :=\text{ potential at any point inside the any colored domain }  $$

We want to deduce the formula of \$V\$

$$  D  :=\text{ electric flux density }　~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{this value is constant at any point between the plates.}   $$

$$  E_{1}=\frac{  D  }{  \epsilon_{1}  }  $$

$$  E_{2}=\frac{  D  }{  \epsilon_{2}  }  $$

The below 2 equations are the problems for me currently.

$$  V'-V_{1}  = E_{1} d_{1}$$

$$  V_{2} -V'= E_{2} d_{2} $$

Concretely I can't get relations of magnitudes of the each potential.

Since

$$ E_{1} d_{1} ~~,~~  E_{2} d_{2} >0 $$

The below inequations must be held.

$$  V_{2} \geq V' \geq V_{1}  \geq 0 $$

How can it be determined?

Why \$V_{2}\$ can be asserted that \$V_{2}\$ takes a highest value?

I thought the below.

$$  Q:=\text{charge at the top plate}  $$

$$ \sigma   :=\text{surface charge density of the top plate}   $$

Since the electric flux density \$D\$ is constant at any point between the plates,

the  surface charge density of the bottom plate can be said \$  -\sigma  \$

By the way and needless to say , \$V'\$ is constant at any point inside the surface of border of the 2 dielectrics.

Of course electric lines of force mostly exist between the plates(few of electric lines of force exist outside between the plates).

What I've been missing or mistaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assumed
$$ E_{1} d_{1} ~~,~~  E_{2} d_{2} >0 $$
you assumed the electric field points upwards. Therefore you assumed the bottom plate is at a higher potential than the top plate.

However, I don't see any reason you should assume the field points upwards.

It's probably better if you assume \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ are known values and use them to calculate \$E_1\$ and \$E_2\$. You might even decide that either \$V_1\$ or \$V_2\$ is taken to be 0 (i.e. is the reference potential) to simplify the calculations.